# How to make a navigation bar flat?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been customizing bootstrap 3 looks for the last couple of days using **bootswatchr** to see my changes live, but, when my `.json` is loaded into bootstrap the navigation bar doesn't look the same.

This is my desired navigation bar looks (as displayed in BootSwatchr):

[image: desired navigation bar looks]

And here's what I got after importing settings into bootstrap:

[image: here's what I got]

My variables:

```
//== Navbar
//
//##

// Basics of a navbar
@navbar-height:                    50px;
@navbar-margin-bottom:             @line-height-computed;
@navbar-border-radius:             1px;//@border-radius-base;
@navbar-padding-horizontal:        floor((@grid-gutter-width / 2));
@navbar-padding-vertical:          ((@navbar-height - @line-height-computed) / 2);
@navbar-collapse-max-height:       340px;

@navbar-default-color:             #777;
@navbar-default-bg:                #123D63;
@navbar-default-border:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);

// Navbar links
@navbar-default-link-color:                #fff;
@navbar-default-link-hover-color:          #fff;
@navbar-default-link-hover-bg:             #57B6D9;
@navbar-default-link-active-color:         #fff;
@navbar-default-link-active-bg:            #2DA4CF;//darken(@navbar-default-link-hover-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-link-disabled-color:       #ccc;
@navbar-default-link-disabled-bg:          transparent;

// Navbar brand label
@navbar-default-brand-color:               @navbar-default-link-color;
@navbar-default-brand-hover-color:         darken(@navbar-default-brand-color, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-brand-hover-bg:            transparent;

// Navbar toggle
@navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg:           #ddd;
@navbar-default-toggle-icon-bar-bg:        #888;
@navbar-default-toggle-border-color:       #ddd;
```

Is there another property that should be modified in order to make my nav bar look as intended?

Should I create a CSS file and modify it from there?

Help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/13217/

Comment: Add a link to jsfiddle that include the relevant css and the menu

Comment: Why does JSFiddle shows it in the correct manner but it's different in my project? What can I do? @Dekel

Comment: The jsfiddle is probably missing some css that you have in your project. The minute you understand what - problem solved :)

Comment: You were absolutely right, @Dekel ... Problem solved by removing bootstrap-theme.min.css link from my view. Thank you very much! (:

Comment: That is exactly why I don't like any frameworks and prefer manual work from start all the way to end - all the frameworks behave only how they are pre-coded and any alteration is very time consuming. Here, I would do some redefinitioning, I would incllude my own css file and dug through the dev console finding relevant classes id ids and overwrite framework definitions by my own (if you link your file last, it will overwrite previous definition. if this will not help, use !important in your definitions

Comment: @Zorak if you take only the basic (bootstrap) without the theme, everything would have worked. The problem was taking the theme and start from it (instead of just work with bootstrap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing an unnecessary css link from the view ...

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```